# custom dojo widget with image display, text title and image description

Tags: image, templates, parameters, dojo, widget

I am trying build a custom dojo 1.9 widget with template support. I need to pass text value and image (stored in POJO) into the widget when I do Instantiation.

I found some example from:

```
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/quickstart/writingWidgets.html#quickstart-writingwidgets
```

there are some templates with text field and button that accept value by using data-dojo-attach-point. But I never find a template example accept image. Does any one have one full example meet my requirement?

```
<div class="${baseClass}" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode"
  data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:_onClick"
  role="menuitem" tabIndex="-1">
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button"
   data-dojo-attach-point="buttonWidget">
   My Button
   </div>
    <span data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode"></span>
  </div>
```

[image: this is the result I am looking for]

Please help!!

Comment: have a look at this [tutorial](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/mobile/flickrview/part2/), it may help you in dealing with images, even though the tutorial is related to mobile web development

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will have a look to see may helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed by myself.

Dojo Dialog and html5 configure tag was used. This way is a work around to support title and image caption, eventually have to wait for dojo LightBoxNano widget (probably 2.0 or newer version) to support image caption.

Dojo snippet code:

```
var theconfigure = "<figure><img src=\"data:"+returnData.fileType+";base64,"+returnData.fileData+"\" width=\"400\" height=\"300\">"+
                  "<figcaption>"+returnData.fileDesc+"</figcaption></figure>";
var myDialog = new dijit.Dialog({
    title: returnData.relatedLocation,
    content: theconfigure,
    style: "width: 410px"
});
myDialog.show();
```

The result looks like:

[image: Image title and caption]